# How do I implement database backed autocomplete fields in my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm looking to use an autocomplete field where users begin to type and a list of suggested genres appear.

First I want to prepopulate the DB with a list of genres, then for these vales to be used in an autocomplete form.

I'm not really looking to build autocomplete from scratch but rather use something that's already out there... so suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Do you want to know how to prepopulate a database with data, or, do you want to know how to autocomplete matching words as the user types in a text field? They're very different questions, and it seems the question can be interpreted two ways.

Comment: I believe he wants to know how to do both.

Comment: yes both... also I'm not really looking to build autocomplete from scratch but rather use something that's already out there

Comment: You should edit your question title to be clear about what you want. In the future, others will benefit from a nice clear title. something like "How do I implement database backed autocomplete fields in my rails app?" perhaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to do is to put your list of genres into a seeds.rb file so you can run `rake db:seed` to get the list into your app when you deploy.

Here's an asciicast to get you up to speed: http://asciicasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data

You'll end up with something like:

```
# app/models/genre.rb
class Genre < ActiveRecord::Base
end

# seeds.rb
["Techno", "New Wave", "Death Metal", "Dubstep"].each do |genre|
  Genre.create!(:display_name => genre)
end
```

Dealing with the autocomplete will be easy, just use this plugin http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/ , and add a GenresController that produces the json required.

Comment: don't you think installing all of jQuery UI is a bit of an overkill just for autocomplete? is there anything else that involves less set up?

Comment: You wanted easy ;) The autocomplete widget doesn't require *all* of jquery ui, just UI Core, UI Widget, and UI Position. You might try  https://github.com/chris/auto_complete_jquery instead, but I imagine it won't be quite as easy as the one I listed above.

Comment: Looks pretty nice. Active, lots of watchers and forks. Looks easy to use as well. I may use that one in my next project

Comment: Yeah it's really nice looking and also very customizable :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want a list of genres, I think a good starting point is the list that ID3v1 supports: http://www.multimediasoft.com/amp3dj/help/index.html?amp3dj_00003e.htm

Comment: Some of these genres are interesting haha

Comment: Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: I mean I was really looking more for the technical things I would need to do. For the genres I was considering just taking the ones that iTunes uses.